# Invalid container name

Tags: angular, docker

I have created a docker image using this command :

```
docker build -t front:Angular4 -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile .
```

Nom i want to just create a container "**containerangular**"  from this image , and as it's a **Angular 4** project VE , i wanna expose the **4200** port of serving in angular to the **4300** port of my host ,

i have used this command :

```
docker run --name -it front:Angular4 -p 4200:4300 -v /usr/share/nginx/logs:/usr/share/nginx/logs -P -t containerangular
```

but that fails indicating an error in the name .

> Error response from daemon: Invalid container name (-it), only
>   [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: The `--name` argument should be followed immediately by a name for the container, not the `-it` arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a little your line to be complaint with the specification

```
docker run --name containerangular -d  -p 4300:4200 -v /usr/share/nginx/logs:/usr/share/nginx/logs front:Angular4
```

Regards